# How do I limit the Staff.NoteHead overrides?

Tags: lilypond

I often have a string of harmonics, so I decided to use a music function (the function is a tangent; if I place the override directly with the notes I get the same problem. The issue is the override itself):

```
harmonics =
#(define-music-function
    (parser location notes)
    (ly:music?)
    #{
        %\harmonicsOn
        \override Staff.NoteHead #'style = #'harmonic-mixed

        $notes

        \revert Staff.NoteHead #'style
        %\harmonicsOff
    #}
    )
```

`\harmonicsOn` and `\harmonicsOff` works, but they're always hollow notes so I don't want to use them. Overriding the notehead allows me to have solid heads on quarter notes.

My problem is that the note heads are overridden for all notes in the duration, not only the notes supplied to the function (see m. 2, 3 in the image below the following code):

```
melody = \relative c' { \stemUp

    \repeat unfold 4 { r8 b g b e' b, | }
    \bar "|."
}

harmony = \relative c' { \stemDown

    e,2. |

    \harmonics { e } |        
    \harmonics { e4 e } s |

    e2. |
}

\score {
    \new Staff {
        \time 3/4 \clef "treble_8"
        \key g \major

    <<
        \new Voice { \melody} \new Voice { \harmony}
    >>
    }
}
```

[image]

I'm looking for a way to modify only the notes I want (in this case, in `\harmony`), leaving the other notes within that duration untouched.

*Edit*: I tried with lilypond 2.17 using the new `\temporary` command, but I get the same result.

[Full code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49933602/SE%20NoteHead%20Question.ly) | [NoteHead Internals Documentation](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.16/Documentation/internals/notehead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your function uses the `\override` command, which affects all simultaneous grobs in a given context, and thus it is changing all noteheads in the Staff context (which contains both melody and harmony music). If you change the noteheads only in the Voice context, then your problem is solved:

```
harmonics =
#(define-music-function
    (parser location notes)
    (ly:music?)
    #{
        %\harmonicsOn
        \override Voice.NoteHead #'style = #'harmonic-mixed
        $notes
        \revert Voice.NoteHead #'style
        %\harmonicsOff
    #}
    )
```

Comment: It also worth mentioning that when you need to change a property for a single grob that has other simultaneous grobs in the same context (such as chords), the command `\tweak` might come in handy. Have a look on these: `{ <a \tweak style #'harmonic-mixed e' cis''>1 }` changes only one notehead inside of a chord, while `{ e'1 -\tweak #'color #red \pp -> }` only changes the colour of the dynamics. Also note that in the last case, the command needs an `-` to work, thus becoming `-\tweak`.